# How to run a single scala test with scoverage?

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

I know that `sbt clean coverage test` will generate coverage report using all test cases on the project, this takes ages to finish even with the warm JVM.

I wish to run coverage on the tests for the code I wrote so, I tried to run a single testcase like `sbt coverage test-only package.ScalaSpec` and I get the following error.

**ERROR**

`[scala-project] $ coverage test-only package.ScalaSpec
<set>:1: error: eof expected but 'package' found.
coverageEnabled in ThisBuild := true test-only package.ScalaSpec
                                               ^
[error] Error parsing expression.`

Comment: For some reason the `sbt coverage "test-only package.ScalaSpec"` didn't work for me, it throws the same exception but this works `sbt coverage "test:testOnly package.ScalaSpec"`

Answer (score 9):

Surround your fully-qualified package name in quotes.

coverage is failing because it is parsing the command as though the `test` goal is the first argument to coverage, and the qualified package name `package.ScalaSpec` as the second.

What you want to do instead is give coverage only one argument like this:
`sbt coverage "testOnly package.ScalaSpec"`

Before, coverage is given the command `test` as its goal, followed by an unexpected 2nd parameter.
After, coverage is given the command `testOnly package.ScalaSpec` as its goal.